# Ruby Watir: How open multiple links from a single page

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I have this scenario:

I have multiple links on a single page , each link is inserted in a table. I extracted some

html code:

```
<td headers="record0_int1">
<a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Primasel2_1_dlstPrimasel_ctl00_PrimoLinkSSel"     title="Consulta la scheda dettagliata del bene con codice A241511" href="/secondasel.aspx?  id=815300&ida=241511&idp=473762&m=1&t=1">A241511</a>
</td>

<td headers="record1_int1">
<a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Primasel2_1_dlstPrimasel_ctl01_PrimoLinkSSel"     title="Consulta la scheda dettagliata del bene con codice A241512" href="/secondasel.aspx? id=815301&ida=241512&idp=473762&m=1&t=1">A241512</a>
</td>
```

**What I'm looking for?**

I need to:

1) get the id `ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Primasel2_1_dlstPrimasel_ctl00_PrimoLinkSSel` , where for each link this ID changes only on a single number, example:

`first id:   ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Primasel2_1_dlstPrimasel_ctl00_PrimoLinkSSel`
    `second id: ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Primasel2_1_dlstPrimasel_ctl01_PrimoLinkSSel`
    `third id:  ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Primasel2_1_dlstPrimasel_ctl02_PrimoLinkSSel`
    `and so on`

2) for each ID extracted I need to open the href link, if possible on a new page!

I'm trying all from yesterday , without any good result :(

Thank you all for each reply ;)

Answer (score 4):

First you can get all of the links by creating a collection based on the static part of the id:

```
links = browser.links(:id => /ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Primasel2_1_dlstPrimasel_ctl\d+_PrimoLinkSSel/)
```

Then you can iterate through the links to click each one. You can do it like a user and hold down the control button to open a new page:

```
links.each { |link| link.click(:control) }
```

Alternatively, you can also force a new window by adding the `target="_blank"` attribute to each link before clicking it.

```
links.each do |link|
  browser.execute_script('arguments[0].setAttribute("target", "_blank");', link)
  link.click
end
```

For Firefox, the second approach seemed to be more stable since it does not rely on native events.

Once you have the pages open, you can get a specific window to work with. For example:

```
browser.window(:title => 'the window title').use do
  puts browser.text
end
```

You could also iterate through the windows, say to output each title:

```
browser.windows.each do |window|
  window.use do
    puts window.title
  end
end
```

Comment: Justin, in this case, how do you access the newly opened browsers?

Comment: @JeffPrice, I added a couple of examples for working with the new browsers. In general, you find the window, say you want to use it, and then use it like any other browser instance.

Comment: wow man it's amazing , it works *-*
How can I save each link opened with for cycle? I need to save each link with unique file name!!

Comment: You could use the example for iterating through each open window and run the code you got in your previous question for how to save a page.